# Vector implemention in C++

Tags: c++, vector

Im trying to implement one of the Vector's Functions which is Resize
As much as I know all the other functions that I implemented are alright

In the test code I tried to print out every possible situation that might happen but when I came to print the size of the new Vector (poitner to integer called _elements)
I get an error "#.exr Triggered a breakpoint
for some odd reason in the tester (main) when i set at the loop "i <8" it works fine but if I do <= it triggers it

I believe the is caused by the resize function but Even after following the debugger I cant seem to find the problem
(explenation of the funtion is in the code)

the vector that I created was successfuly intelized for those who might wonder

Why is this happening?

the function with the following inputs / outputs  are:

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& other)
{
    _elements = new int;
    _size = other._size;
    _capacity = other._capacity;
    _resizeFactor = other._resizeFactor;
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
    {
        _elements[i] = other._elements[i];
    }

}

//change _size to n, unless n is greater than the vector's capacity
//same as above, if new elements added their value is val
void Vector::resize(int n, const int& val)  
{
    if (n <= _capacity)
    {
        while (n < _size)
        {
            pop_back();
        }

        while (n > _size)
        {
            push_back(val);
        }

        _capacity = n;

    }
    else if (n > _capacity)
    {

        reserve(n);
        while (n > _size)
        {
            push_back(val);

        }
    }
}

//change the  capacity
void Vector::reserve(int n)                 
{

    if (n > _capacity)
    {
        int size = _resizeFactor;
        while (n - _capacity > size)
        {
            size = size + _resizeFactor;
        }
        _capacity += size;
    }
}



//adds element at the end of the vector
void Vector::push_back(const int& val)
{

    if (_size < _capacity)
    {
        _elements[_size] = val;
        _size++;    
    }
    else if (_size == _capacity)
    {
        int* a = new int[_capacity + _resizeFactor];
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        {
            a[i] = _elements[i];
        }

        _capacity += _resizeFactor;
        _elements = new int[_capacity];

        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        {
            _elements[i] = a[i];
        }
        delete a;
        _elements[_size] = val;
        _size++;
    }
}


void Vector::pop_back()         
{
    if (_size > 0)
    {
        _elements[_size] = NULL;
        _size--;
    }
}
```

and I check it with

```
void print(const Vector& p)
{

    cout << "Size = " << p.size() << ", Capacity = " << p.capacity() << ",      isEmpty = " << (p.empty() ? "True" : "False") << endl;
}
```

and in main:

```
Vector a(10);
for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    a.push_back(i+1);
print(a);
a.push_back(10);
print(a);
a.push_back(11);
print(a);
int x = 99;
a.resize(a.capacity() + 11, x);
print(a);
```

Comment: What's the purpose of rolling your own implementation of `std::vector`? You could learn by studying your compiler's implementation of it.

Comment: I am learning C++ and this is how I was told to do it

Comment: Show your *entire* program, any imput you gave it, and the output it produced, *verbatim*.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Attempting to read and understand any standard library implementation for the big compilers is pretty much useless. The code is very hard to understand unless you already knows what's happening, and possible optimizations makes it even worse.

Comment: What you posted clearly isn't *everything*. And as a general rule, the hardest errors to find are those in places where you aren't looking.

Comment: I added everything I was suppose to , to prevent usless information and overload

Comment: Why do you set `_capacity` to `n` in `resize`?

Comment: Since you don't know why the problem occurs, you don't know which information is useful for its resolution and which is not. [This is why MCVE was invented](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).